# How to access funds if the Gnosis Safe website is shutdown?

Tags: contract-invocation, gnosis-safe, raw-transaction, recovery

Imagine that the Gnosis Safe website and services is shutdown, how can users access their funds?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access your funds you should keep your Safe address noted somewhere with you and you can go to that Safe address blockexplorer and you can use execTranasction function . In order to fill its parameter you need to encode the functions and sign them to get your signature . This is very technical if this all needs to be done by a non-tech user. In the end in order for a non-tech person to interact with its fund is to hope that site and services dont go down

Hope this helps